# newbie to bootstrap - popover code not working correctly

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to dynamicly load content into the popover on click, 

I don't see the popover content changing

```
 $('a#popover-link').popover("content", "New Content for Popover");
```

Sample code:
http://jsfiddle.net/848SQ/2/

What am I doing wrong?

Is there any difference between bootstrap popover and JQuery popover?

 Thank you

Comment: Do you want it in jquery OR twitter-bootstrap?

Comment: I'd start by using a version of Bootstrap newer than 1.4.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Bootstrap 2.3.2, try something like this

```
var content = 'Loading...';
$('a#popover-link').popover({
    placement : 'right',
    title : 'popover title',
    html: 'false',
    trigger:'hover',
    content :function() { return content; }
});

$('a#popover-link').click(function(){      
    var link = $('a#popover-link').popover("hide");
    content = 'New content for popover';
    link.popover('show');
});
```

Example - http://jsfiddle.net/848SQ/3/